# Unitek Y-247A USB sound card frequency response

Tags: sound

I've been sucessfully using the Unitek Y-247A USB sound card
on Ubuntu, including 20.04, for a number of years now.

As this purportedly uses dedicated two channel DAC and two channel ADC, all 16 bit, I'm now wondering what the frequency
response and power output is. I'm also wondering if this is
capable of dc output and input.